# Publishing data from Rust to Ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, how can I publish data from rust to ROS running on two different computers.
I am trying to use the following library but it does not contain any example for my use case where I want to transfer my data to another computer where ROS will be running.

https://github.com/adnanademovic/rosrust

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409083/publishing-data-from-rust-to-ros/) by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2022-11-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-11-07**:
I think you wanted to copy & paste a link to this library/write its name, but it is not here. Please update your question.

**Comment by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on 2022-11-07**:
I updated the question.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-11-07**:
This question may be related to #q409094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figure out that It is essential to run rosbridge on the computer where you want to send data to. After installing rosbridge using the following command `sudo apt-get install ros-<rosdistro>-rosbridge-server` and launching using the command `roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch` it was working perfectly. I would like to suggest to take care of the port number as rosbridge usually use 9090 and any different port number in the code could lead to error.

I am closing this issue as it has been solved. If the problem persists, please comment and the issue will be reopened if appropriate.

---

Originally posted by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) with karma: 61 on 2022-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0